# x86_64 gcc inline assembly constraints for rax, rbx,

Tags: gcc, clang, inline-assembly

In the following:

```
#include <string.h>

struct cpuidOut
{
   long a ;
   long b ;
   long c ;
   long d ;
} ;

void callcpuid( cpuidOut * p, long a )
{
   memset( p, 0xFF, sizeof(*p) ) ;
   p->a = a ;

   __asm__ ( "cpuid"
             : "+a"(p->a), "=b"(p->b), "=c"(p->c), "=d"(p->d)  // output
             :                                                 // no (only) inputs
             : "a", "b", "c", "d"                              // clobbered registers
           ) ;
}
```

I get a compile error:

```
t.C:22: error: unknown register name 'd' in 'asm'
t.C:22: error: unknown register name 'c' in 'asm'
t.C:22: error: unknown register name 'b' in 'asm'
t.C:22: error: unknown register name 'a' in 'asm'
```

(same sort of error from either g++ or clang++)

This suprises me since I see a, b, c, d listed in the i386 clobbers in the gcc documentation

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints

I can fix the clobber constraints by being explicit:

```
"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"                  // clobbered registers
```

but I'm suprised I have to do so?  I only need this to work on x86_64, but I thought the "a", "b", "c", "d" style constraints would be nicer in case the code is later needed on i386 too.

EDIT: I'd initially posted the wrong asm after tweaking it a couple of times trying to get it to work, and getting mixed up along the way.  The asm above is consistent with my initial question, however, causes a compile error with the compiler unable to schedule the A register.  This seems to work instead:

```
void callcpuid( cpuidOut * p, long a, long b )
{
   __asm__ ( "cpuid"
             : "=a"(p->a), "=b"(p->b), "=c"(p->c), "=d"(p->d)  // output
             : "0"(a), "1"(b)                                  // inputs
           ) ;
}
```

but notice that it avoids the requirement for any clobber constraints at all, since all the clobbers are outputs.  That's probably the right way to do it, although I'm still suprised after reading the gcc docs that I can't use the generic reg names "a", "b", "c", "d" in the clobber constraints, instead having to use "%eax", "%rax", ...

Comment: Depending on the use of PIC and the memory model, you might need to save `EBX/RBX` because, according to the ABI specification, the caller owns it. The `"=b"(p->b)` destroys `EBX/RBX`.

Comment: If I list rbx as an output, won't the compiler have to do a spill for -fpic itself (as opposed to me having to do it explicitly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This suprises me since I see a, b, c, d listed in the i386 clobbers in the gcc documentation

The clobbers are not constraints.

Constraints are used when you tell GCC to allocate registers for insn operands, the constraints define the acceptable register class from which to draw registers.

The clobbers, on the other hand, tell GCC  about registers, which are modified by the insns, in the cases where it's not evident from the input/output constraints, for example an insn, which modifies a fixed register, which is not one of its operands or when you use hardcoded register names in the inline assembly.

This is needed, so before execution of the inline asm, GCC can stash away values, that it happens to keep in the clobbered registers.

PS. For input-output operands, you can used the `"+"` modifier:

```
void callcpuid( cpuidOut * p, long a, long b )
{
   __asm__ ( "cpuid" : "+a"(p->a), "+b"(p->b), "=c"(p->c), "=d"(p->d)) ;
}
```

PS. 32-bit code generated:

```
movl    (%esi), %eax  ; load p->a
movl    4(%esi), %ebx ; load p->b
cpuid
movl    %ebx, 4(%esi)  ; write back into p->b
movl    (%esp), %ebx   
movl    %eax, (%esi)   ; write back into p->a
movl    %ecx, 8(%esi)  ; write p->c
movl    %edx, 12(%esi) ; write p->d
```

64-bit code generated:

```
movq    (%rdi), %rax   ; load p->a
movq    8(%rdi), %rbx  ; load p->b
cpuid
movq    %rbx, 8(%rdi)  ; write back p->b
movq    %rax, (%rdi)   ; write back p->a
movq    %rcx, 16(%rdi) ; write p->c
movq    %rdx, 24(%rdi) ; write p->d
```

Comment: Thanks.  I always called them clobber constraints, so it looks like I confused myself just by nomenclature.

ps.  Your sample with + doesn't do the job since it doesn't get the `a`, and `b` parameters into `p->a`, `p->b` respectively.

Comment: Oh, it does work, I've used it many times and in fact I checked it on this example as well. Check edit in a second.

Comment: All I'm saying is that in my sample the two parameters `a` and `b` were inputs.  You have a different interface with a pair of unused parameters.  If you removed those two parameters and required that the values be put into the structure instead, your code would do the job (which isn't a bad way to do it).

Comment: Be careful with that call to `callcpuid`. Depending on the memory model and the use of PIC, `EBX/RBX` may need to be preserved. Then, when you try to preserve `EBX/RBX`, you run into goodness like [What ensures reads/writes of operands occurs at desired times with extended ASM?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32099922)

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait for the next GCC 4.8 release, or if you can use the latest snapshot of GCC (i.e. compile the trunk from svn source), consider using the new [builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html#X86-Built_002din-Functions) `__builtin_cpu_is` and `__builtin_cpu_supports`;

otherwise, do what you suggest, e.g. be explicit with clobber constraints.

NB: the [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) you refer to is also for future GCC 4.8, not for 4.7 or earlier

Comment: Good suggestion.  My final target compiler is actually clang in this case (which implements gcc style asm) ... was just test compiling the code in question.