# What ensures reads/writes of operands occurs at desired timed with extended ASM?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

According to GCC's [Extended ASM and Assembler Template](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate), to keep instructions consecutive, they must be in the same ASM block. I'm having trouble understanding what provides the scheduling or timings of reads and writes to the operands in a block with multiple statements.

As an example, `EBX` or `RBX` needs to be preserved when using `CPUID` because, according to the ABI, the caller owns it. There are some open questions with respect to the use of `EBX` and `RBX`, so we want to preserve it unconditionally (its a requirement). So three instructions need to be encoded into a single ASM block to ensure the consecutive-ness of the instructions (re: the assembler template discussed in the first paragraph):

```
unsigned int __FUNC = 1, __SUBFUNC = 0;
unsigned int __EAX, __EBX, __ECX, __EDX;

__asm__ __volatile__ (

  "push %ebx;"
  "cpuid;"
  "pop %ebx"
  : "=a"(__EAX), "=b"(__EBX), "=c"(__ECX), "=d"(__EDX)
  : "a"(__FUNC), "c"(__SUBFUNC)

);
```

If the expression representing the operands is interpreted at the wrong point in time, then `__EBX` will be the saved `EBX` (and not the `CPUID`'s `EBX`), which will likely be a pointer to the Global Offset Table (GOT) if PIC is enabled.

Where, exactly, does the expression specify that the store of `CPUID`'s `%EBX` into `__EBX` should happen (1) after the `PUSH %EBX`; (2) after the `CPUID`; but (3) before the `POP %EBX`?

Comment: Where does the documentation state gcc will reorder assembler instructions in a single asm block?

Comment: @Olaf It's not about the instructions, it's about the parameters of the block.

Comment: The input and output constraints apply before and after the whole block, respectively. That also means your code is wrong, because you are saving the restored `ebx`. Also note that if you specify a register as output, the compiler knows it has been modified. Furthermore, the ABI applies to function calls only, for inline asm you need to tell the compiler about **all** registers that you modify either as output or clobber. You generally don't need to save/restore them, the compiler can do that better.

Comment: @Olaf - *"Where does the documentation state gcc ..."* - I cited the doc; its the one that discusses assembler templates. Search for the word "consecutive". (And please note that I did not use the word *"reorder"*; you did).

Comment: @ElderBug - *"That also means your code is wrong..."* - that's what I thought. So how do we express this when taking "consecutive-ness" into account, which means it has to be in a multi-statement block?

Comment: The correct code for this is just `"cpuid"`, since `ebx` does not need to be preserved given it's listed as output.

Comment: @Olaf the output constraints instruct the compiler to generate those mov instructions (if needed).

Comment: @Jester - According to [Proper use of x86/x86_64 CPUID instruction with extended assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-08/msg00088.html) on the GCC mailing list, `EBX` or `RBX` needs to be manually saved and restored. Even the GCC patches for GCC do it.

Comment: @ElderBug  - sorry about that. Its too late to change it now. My apologies.

Comment: @jww actually the problem there is that when compiling PIC, the compiler simply does not allow you to use the `"b"` constraint (it says `error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'`). To work around that, indeed you need to save `ebx` because you can't list it as output or clobber. For usual code, you can use `"b"` directly (the linked patch does this too).

Comment: @Jester - *"...the compiler simply does not allow you to use the "b" constraint ..."* - OK, I'm getting different results. For example, under Cygwin i386, there is no complaint. Cygwin is using the GCC 4.9 compiler. And I did not have problems when testing under under Debian 8/i386 and Fedora 22/i686. I believe they use the GCC 4.9 and 5.1 compilers, respectively.

Comment: @Jester - as an academic exercise, how can I use all of this in a multi-asm block? "All of this" is (1) save `EBX`, (2) execute `CPUID`, (3) save the results, and (4) restore `EBX`. How should I write the multi-asm statement block? (Your ASM mojo is much better than mine).

Comment: @Jester - is the problem here that we ***cannot*** use Extended ASM to solve this problem?

Comment: @jww : When you tested what @jester said did you compile it with `-fPIC`?   Joker prefaced _"the compiler simply does not allow you to use the "b" constraint ..."_ with _"the problem there is that when compiling PIC"_ ?

Comment: @Michael - Yes. In fact, Cygwin enables it by default.

Comment: @jww Peculiar unless you were generating 64bit code.

Comment: @Michael - yeah, but its kind of par for the course at times. Hence the reason we want to unconditionally save `EBX/RBX`. With it unconditionally saved, all these sidebar questions (like "why is Cygwin not complaining about a constraint violation" and "are the ABI requirements being met") simply go away.

Comment: @Jester - *"That also means your code is wrong..."* - by the way, you should provide an answer since that answers the question at hand. That was exactly what I was wondering about.

Comment: Couldn't you manually move `ebx` to variable `__EBX` prior to the `pop`?

Comment: @Michael - that's actually kind of tricky... On x86_64, `CPUID` still uses `EAX` and friends. But the 64-bit `RBX` needs to be preserved. I was even thinking to declare an extra C variable to handle it. But if I can't control when the constraints or operands are evaluated, then its a moot point.

Comment: My understanding has always been that gcc `asm` blocks are seen as a text passed onto the assembler verbatim (The compiler doesn't modify such code). That would imply the constraint would have to be outside the assembler block some point after `pop %ebx`

Comment: @Michael - OK, then I think that leads us back to the problem of ensuring the consecutive-ness of multi-line asm statements and the assembler template :)

Comment: Isn't that already handled in the spec for GCC: "Do not expect a *sequence* of **asm** _statements_ to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation, " A single `__asm__` statement with multiple instructions won't be rearranged but separate `__asm__` statements may be.

Comment: @Michael - *"Isn't that already handled in the spec for GCC..."* - yes, that's why we are trying to do this from a single, multi-line ASM block. But to use the multi-line ASM block, we need to ensure operands are read from and written to at the correct times.

Comment: @jww I don't think everyone knows what you mean by "correct time". You have 3 assembly instruction here. They're executed in the order you wrote them, and they work just like the intel manuals say they do. Where does time enter the picture, and how could operands not be read/written from at the correct time ?

Comment: Note that in 64 bit code, this is a non-issue because `rbx` is not used as the GOT pointer since 64 bit uses rip-relative addressing, and indeed the `"b"` constraint works fine in 64 bit mode (at least on my linux machine).

Comment: According to cpuid.h on x86_64 whether `rbx` is saved or not is also dependent on the memory model. Retaining the state of `rbx` is done when this is true `#elif defined(__x86_64__) && (defined(__code_model_medium__) || defined(__code_model_large__)) && defined(__PIC__)`

Comment: @MichaelPetch yeah makes sense since rip-relative addressing might not work in those cases.

Comment: @nos - I'm probably splitting hairs, but I never said "correct time" (I even checked history). How the operands are not read/written at the expected times is explained in the body (like which `EBX` is being written to which C variable at which point in time). I'm very open to suggestions because its hard to capture the essence of the question for the title. I was having such a hard time with it, the question sat unsubmitted for about 4 hours while I thought about how to phrase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you present some code that does a `push` and `pop` of `ebx`. The idea of saving `ebx` in the event that you compile with gcc using `-fPIC` (position independent code) is correct. It is up to our function not to clobber `ebx` upon return in that situation. Unfortunately the way you have defined the constraints you explicitly use `ebx`. Generally the compiler will warn you (*error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'*) if you are using PIC code and you specify `=b` as an output constraint. Why it doesn't produce a warning for you is unusual.

To get around this problem you can let the assembler template choose a register for you. Instead of pushing and popping we simply exchange `%ebx` with an unused register chosen by the compiler and restore it by exchanging it back after. Since we don't wish to have the compiler clobber our input registers during the exchange we specify early clobber modifier, thus ending up with a constraint of `=&r` (instead of `=b` in the OPs code). More on modifiers can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers). Your code (for 32 bit) would look something like:

```
unsigned int __FUNC = 1, __SUBFUNC = 0;
unsigned int __EAX, __EBX, __ECX, __EDX;

__asm__ __volatile__ (
       "xchgl\t%%ebx, %k1\n\t"      \
       "cpuid\n\t"                  \
       "xchgl\t%%ebx, %k1\n\t"

  : "=a"(__EAX), "=&r"(__EBX), "=c"(__ECX), "=d"(__EDX)
  : "a"(__FUNC), "c"(__SUBFUNC));
```

If you intend to compile for X86_64 (64 bit) you'll need to save the entire contents of `%rbx`. The code above will not quite work. You'd have to use something like:

```
uint32_t  __FUNC = 1, __SUBFUNC = 0;
uint32_t __EAX, __ECX, __EDX;
uint64_t __BX; /* Big enough to hold a 64 bit value */

__asm__ __volatile__ (
       "xchgq\t%%rbx, %q1\n\t"      \
       "cpuid\n\t"                  \
       "xchgq\t%%rbx, %q1\n\t"

  : "=a"(__EAX), "=&r"(__BX), "=c"(__ECX), "=d"(__EDX)
  : "a"(__FUNC), "c"(__SUBFUNC));
```

You could code this up using conditional compilation to deal with both X86_64 and i386:

```
uint32_t  __FUNC = 1, __SUBFUNC = 0;
uint32_t __EAX, __ECX, __EDX;
uint64_t __BX; /* Big enough to hold a 64 bit value */

#if defined(__i386__)
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
           "xchgl\t%%ebx, %k1\n\t"      \
           "cpuid\n\t"                  \
           "xchgl\t%%ebx, %k1\n\t"

      : "=a"(__EAX), "=&r"(__BX), "=c"(__ECX), "=d"(__EDX)
      : "a"(__FUNC), "c"(__SUBFUNC));

#elif defined(__x86_64__)
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
           "xchgq\t%%rbx, %q1\n\t"      \
           "cpuid\n\t"                  \
           "xchgq\t%%rbx, %q1\n\t"

      : "=a"(__EAX), "=&r"(__BX), "=c"(__ECX), "=d"(__EDX)
      : "a"(__FUNC), "c"(__SUBFUNC));
#else
#error "Unknown architecture."
#endif
```

GCC has a `__cpuid` macro defined in `cpuid.h`. It defined the macro so that it only saves the `ebx` and `rbx` register when required. You can find the GCC 4.8.1 macro definition here to get an idea of how they handle `cpuid` in [cpuid.h](http://denemo.org/~jjbenham/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.8.1/include/cpuid.h).

The astute reader may ask the question - what stops the compiler from choosing `ebx` or `rbx` as the scratch register to use for the exchange. The compiler knows about `ebx` and `rbx` in the context of PIC, and will not allow it to be used as a scratch register. This is based on my personal observations over the years and reviewing the assembler (.s) files generated from C code. I can't say for certain how more ancient versions of gcc handled it so it could be a problem.

Comment: *"Why it doesn't produce a warning for you is unusual."* It gets even better. This is for the [Crypto++ library](http://www.cryptopp.com/). I have test platforms set-up going back to GCC 2.9 and 3.x (about 30 in all, with 22 for Linux and GCC). Odd behavior for just one or two platforms would be warmly welcomed :)

Comment: Oh, so when there was no warning generated at compile time, that was with GCC 2.9 or early 3.x? Does a newer (4.x) compiler throw up a warning?

Comment: If one wanted to force the compiler to use a particular register to exchange into one might wish to consider replacing `=&r` with `=D` which would specifically use `%esi` or `%rsi`.

Comment: Now a related question: [Generated code not matching expectations with Extended ASM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32131003). I'm really beginning to dislike GCC's inline assembly. Its too damn limited in that (1) we cannot use local C/C++ variables directly, like `movl %eax, c_variable`; and (2) we cannot enforce "consecutive-ness" without Extended ASM and assembler templates.

Comment: You can pass a variable into the assembler template as an input constraint and then reference it as a positional argument inside the assembler template.

Comment: I tried using positional arguments before asking these two questions. I can't begin to express what a joy it was. The manual is about as clear as mud, and it resulted in a spectacular failure of incomprehensible error messages that pointed to the closing paren of the extended ASM block (and not the line number of the offender). But I'm getting ready to back to it so I can take complete control of things because I don't trust the code being generated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you understand, but to be clear, the "consecutive" rule means that this:

```
asm ("a");
asm ("b");
asm ("c");
```

... might get other instructions interposed, so if that's not desirable then it must be rewritten like this:

```
asm ("a\n"
     "b\n"
     "c");
```

... and now it will be inserted as a whole.

---

As for the `cpuid` snippet, we have two problems:

1. The `cpuid` instruction will overwrite `ebx`, and hence clobber the data that PIC code must keep there.
2. We want to extract the value that `cpuid` places in `ebx` while never returning to compiled code with the "wrong" `ebx` value.

One possible solution would be this:

```
unsigned int __FUNC = 1, __SUBFUNC = 0;
unsigned int __EAX, __EBX, __ECX, __EDX;

__asm__ __volatile__ (    
  "push %ebx;"
  "cpuid;"
  "mov %ebx, %ecx"
  "pop %ebx"
  : "=c"(__EBX)
  : "a"(__FUNC), "c"(__SUBFUNC)
  : "eax", "edx"
);
__asm__ __volatile__ (    
  "push %ebx;"
  "cpuid;"
  "pop %ebx"
  : "=a"(__EAX), "=c"(__ECX), "=d"(__EDX)
  : "a"(__FUNC), "c"(__SUBFUNC)
);
```

There's no need to mark `ebx` as clobbered as you're putting it back how you found it.

(I don't do much Intel programming, so I may have some of the assembler-specific details off there, but this is how `asm` works.)

Comment: That's kind of an interesting approach - call `CPUID` twice. I tried unwinding the terseness of the extended ASM into explicit ASM like `movl %eax, %1", but I can't get the damn assembler to accept it. Maybe this is the solution.

Comment: If you were wondering how to implement cpuid I could have suggested you look directly at cpuid.h (should be a copy on your system, but you can find it online). In particular `__cpuid` macro which uses an assembler directive. It uses `xchg` instead of `push` and `pop` and uses an output register of "=r" (used with `xchg`). https://github.com/infphilo/hisat/blob/master/third_party/cpuid.h

Comment: @jww Like I said, I'm not completely sure what the x86 assembler syntax should look like, so please correct me if it's wrong. You should indeed be able to substitute `%ecx` with `%0` but there's no real need to.

Comment: @Michael - thanks. As crazy as it sounds, the site does not allow us to ask certain question. So a more direct question (like "How do I do X" or "Please show me an implementation that meets X and Y requirements") may have been closed as off-topic. So we have craft questions that comply with the site's policies and endure the indirect route. It sucks at times (like now), but that's how the site is.

Comment: No problem. On a side note I should point out that I wasn't the one who voted to close ;-) . Someone else can formulate an answer based on my comment if they wish but if they don't by days end I will (when I have a bit of time)

Comment: @Michael - the GitHub code looks a lot [GCC Patch: Introduce cpuid.h and use it everywhere](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-09/msg00324.html). I actually tried to get feedback on it at the GCC Help mailing list; see [Proper use of x86/x86_64 CPUID instruction with extended assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-08/msg00088.html).

Comment: @Michael - *"On a side note I should point out that I wasn't the one who voted to close..."* - Oh, not at all. I'm fair game for closes (I even vote to close some of my earliest questions (did I really ask that in that manner :o)). I'm pretty sure I know who it was. He and I have had problems in the past.

Comment: The link I posted was the wrong one. I meant to post this one which was from gcc 4.8: http://denemo.org/~jjbenham/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.8.1/include/cpuid.h . In particular this one deals with X86_64 and i386 (32 bit). You'll note that the macro is defined differently for 64 and 32 bit compilation.

Comment: jww's linked snippet works around the problem by using another free register of the compiler's choice (hence the `"r"` constraint), so it doesn't need to double the `cpuid`.

Comment: @Jester thanks for fixing it. I wasnt AT&T order, it was ARM order, so doubly wrong. ;-)